# Avoid double clicking submit with validator display set to dynamic

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I have some ASP.NET CustomValidators with `Display="Dynamic"`.  The layout of the page requires that I use them like this without a ValidationSummary.

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="vldFirstThree" ControlToValidate="txtFirstThree" runat="server" OnServerValidate="ValidateTextBox" ValidateEmptyText="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter the first three characters of the owner name.<br />" CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true"/>
```

If the user leaves the field blank and clicks submit, the error text is displayed.  If the user fixes the problem and then clicks submit again, the validation error text clears, but a second click is required to submit the page.  I've tried writing some server-side code and some JavaScript to cause the validated TextBox to `blur()` before submitting, but I'm still running into the need to click twice: once to clear the message and again to submit.

Is there a way to clear the error text and perform the submit with one click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the second one here: [RequiredFieldValidator have to click twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121725/requiredfieldvalidator-have-to-click-twice).

I had to set `EnableClientScript="false"`.