# Javascript issue: Unable to postback on save button click in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox and save button on a pop-up, the textbox has a required field validator. I have a scenario, if the user accidentally forgets to enter data in the textbox and click save the required field validator kicks in, which is expected. But, now if the user enters data in the textbox and clicks on 'save', the record doesn't get saved on the first click instead it needs an additional click. I know the reason for this: it is not doing a postback when the button is clicked for first time, but for the second time it does and saves the data.

Does anyone know the workaround for this? The end user is getting annoyed by that additional click. Please note there is no javascript function associated with it. It is autogenerated javascript from the browser.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" AssociatedControlID="txtTitle">
                                                    Title<span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtTitle" >
                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTitle" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ValidationGroup="questionTitle" CssClass="text-danger">
                                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Save button:

```
 <div class="row">


<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSave" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success btn-lg" role="button" ValidationGroup="questionTitle" OnClick="lnkSave_Click">
                            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp;Save
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a common issue with the validator.

The validator error is suppose to clear out when lose focus to the textbox

however, apparently if your validator `Display` is set to `Dynamic`, when the error message appear, it will cause the triggering clearing the validator error to fail.

hence the clicking twice (first click trigger clear error which should have been trigger earlier but failed, second trigger actual form post)

solution is to change your RequiredFieldValidator `Display` to `Static`

more info checkout

[RequiredFieldValidator have to click twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121725/requiredfieldvalidator-have-to-click-twice)
[RequiredFieldValidator requires user to click twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086471/requiredfieldvalidator-requires-user-to-click-twice)

Comment: @user3147594 glad you got it sorted.  Kindly reminder if it solved your answer please mark as answer so that future reader can see it clearly.